# math.random() only returns 1?

Tags: math, lua

I was trying to generate a random number in between 1,100 but when i print the number it always returns 1

this is my current code:

```
local num = 100
local randomNum = math.random(1,num)
print(randomNum) --> 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's `math.random()` "is an interface to the underling pseudo-random generator function provided by C". You need to seed the random number generator using `math.randomseed()` if you want different results on successive runs of your program. One common approach is to seed the pseudo-random number generator with the current time.

If you change your program to print 10 results of `math.random()`, you'll get a sequence of 10 random-looking numbers -- and that sequence will be the same every time you run your program.

See the `rand()` and `srand()` functions in C.

Note that C's `rand()` typically does not produce high quality pseudo-random numbers. They're likely to be good enough for a game, but not nearly good enough for cryptography.

(On my system, I get `85` every time I run your program. It's going to vary depending on the characteristics of the C runtime library.)